# Problem In Getting Image id In android studio

Tags: java, android

this is my adaptor class ,here i am trying to build like button effect,but every time i clicked any image of mine the other image of my id(ie.user id ) gets liked automatically means colour of like button of the other image also turns red...so i just wanted know what iam doing wrong...i am vary new to android studio...if somebody could help

//this mine firebase database image from here i want image to be like

zone-3af06
MBlog
-M48bKT9NGnY0w-H7Ikg
desc: 
"...."
image: 
"https://"
postid: 
""
timestamp: 
"1586077980415"
title: 
"...."
userid: 
""
username: 
""
-M48bSbuJJZZZI7y4kIX
desc: 
"kkk"
image: 
"https://firebasestorage"
postid: 
""
timestamp: 
"1586078013808"
title: 
"ooo"
userid: 
""
username: 
""

//like funcalling

```
    isLiked(blog.getUserid(), holder.like);
    nrLikes(holder.likes, blog.getUserid());

    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(blog.getUserid())
                        .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(blog.getUserid())
                        .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
            }
        }
    });
```

//user like function
    private void isLiked(String userid, final ImageView imageView) {
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

## Heading

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(userid);
  //  String uid = reference.child("users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                imageView.setTag("liked");
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                imageView.setTag("like");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

//count of user likes
private void nrLikes(final TextView likes, String userid) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(userid);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            likes.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " Likes");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post the error sanyam

Comment: error is that after writing getRef(position).getKey()  inside child() ,getRef() function shows that cannot resolve symbol geRef()...i  just want to delete perticular item from my Mblog database which i have shown above...could U please help me out.

Comment: can you share the complete logcat, and edit it in your question

Comment: Actually i want to get the id of current object so that i coul delete that post...so the above code is the logic which dlete the post but when i write getUri() inside child class like  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MBlog").child(getRef(position).getKey()).removeValue();
             }           then then that function shows cannot resolve symbol getRef() this the error ...because after writing this i get red line on getRef()

Comment: i said you should post the logcat , because you're getting an error , you didn't post the logcat that is the reason nobody has answered you, and i think the reference you're trying to delete does not exist

Comment: posted the logcat...

Comment: are you saving the Uri in the firebase

Comment: can you also post the code where the errors are

Comment: i am using this to get id            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("MBlog");
        final String uid = mDatabaseReference.push().getKey();

Comment: Yes i am saving uri in database, below are the content that i am saving my database    MBlog -M48bKT9NGnY0w-H7Ikg desc: "...." image: "" postid: "" timestamp: "1586077980415" title: "...." userid: "vv91RuBJinNSqkFSVNQNaSgerAW2" username: ""

Comment: you cannot save uri to firebase

Comment: are in your question you are showing firebase code but in log i can't see any firebase error , it is sqlite error there, why? you're using sqlite too

Comment: i am not using any sql code all things have done in firebase and about uri it is saving in firebase database i can see it in  my firebase data base the below are the content which i can see in my database image contain uri                                                   
     MBlog -M48bKT9NGnY0w-H7Ikg desc: "...."                 desc: "...."                                                                                                                 image: ""    postid: ""                timestamp: "1586077980415"

Comment: imageUrl = blog.getImage();


        //TODO: Use Picasso library to load image
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(holder.image);

Comment: are you trying to save Uri object to firebase or the string representation of the uri

Comment: Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    while(!uri.isComplete());
                    Uri downloadurl = uri.getResult();                                                                                               dataToSave.put("image", downloadurl.toString());

Comment: firest i ma taking image in uri object then converting it into tostring

Comment: I editted my Question could U tell me Know whats the problem is...